# Allowing location access inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, geolocation

I have a webview based application and when I access http://maps.google.com, my webview is not passing the location as Safari does. I know CLLocationManager is needed, but do I get a callback when a webpage (maps.google.com) wants access to my device location? How do I respond back with the coordinates to the webpage from my WebView?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The webview will start monitoring the location automatically, however since iOS 8 location access requires the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` description in your info plist to be set.

If this has been done, it will prompt the user automatically to allow location access.

Comment: Sorry about that Tim. Don't really remember the entries in the plist. It's been some time now. I remember I had 2 entires in the plist. Nevertheless, accepted your answer ;)

Comment: @TimBodeit: Should NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription do the trick for Xamarin WebView? Actually I tried, but not luck..